# cakephp find with count equivalent with this query

Tags: php, cakephp

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` where usergroup_id = 4 AND studio_id = 380 AND userstatus_id = 1
```

On this query I am getting a result of `4` which is my expected output, but when doing this query:

```
$this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array(
                                        'User.studio_id'=>380,
                                        'User.usergroup_id'=>4,
                                        'User.userstatus_id'=>1)))
```

I am getting a result of `8`

What do you think is the problem here? Feels like my 2nd code is wrong.

I am a newbie in cakePHP.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `count(*)` in `find` function call?

Comment: look through the sql dump whether sql join give unwanted table association too or not.

Comment: try to set recursive to 0 or -1 and then see if it return result that u want

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im if I change the code that way, it gives me error, I think find('count') is correct.

Comment: @DipeshParmar what recursive?

Comment: @ElsonSolano right you are. my mistake

Comment: recursive is the depth for cakephp query. Suppose if u want query to find record which are nested related then set it to 1 you will get all the sub related data. where 0 go only directly related data.

Comment: just set it before query like $this->User->recursive = 0;

Comment: I already added it but still i'm not getting my expected result. Totally weird, I thought that 2nd query above is just the same on the 1st query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query and the CakePHP `find('count', ...` should produce the same thing.  The likely difference (per a few of the comments) is your `$recursive` level (see [CakePHP recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)).

I'm a big fan of just setting:

```
public $recursive = -1;
```

in your AppModel - then you don't have to worry about it ever again, as leaving it at -1 is best practice IMO.  Then, if you ever want to retrieve additional associated model data, just use [CakePHP's Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

If you don't want to set it to -1 across the entire site, just set it right before your query:

```
$this->User->recursive = -1;
$this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array(
    'User.studio_id'=>380,
    'User.usergroup_id'=>4,
    'User.userstatus_id'=>1
)));
```

**Site Note:** Setting `$recursive` to ANYTHING other than -1 should be a red flag.  It's kind of a cool concept, but in practice, it will cause you many headaches as your site grows.  Set it to -1 in the AppModel like suggested above, then forget it even exists.

Comment: wow! that works like a charm! indeed i'm a newbie in cakephp. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano - no worries - we've all been there.  Glad to help!

Comment: Been using other frameworks such as Yii, but never ran something like this problem even if this problems seems too easy too solve.

Comment: @ElsonSolano - I believe they're planning on removing `$recursive` from future versions of CakePHP - you're not the only one surprised that by default it returns "extra" data.  Again - cool in concept, but - in practice, it's more pain than it's worth, especially since they provide the amazing Containable Behavior.